# SVN Committing files and folder from unversioned local data to two different repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

This is my first question posting on stackoverflow, hope I am framing it cotrrectly!

We are working with 2 different repositories, our work flow is:

1. From repository one, take the data on local machine which has got
   reference to SVN repository one (Could be Trunk Or Specific Tag)
2. Work on this copy
3. At the end of the evey day, I want to upload all the work done to SVN        repository Two
4. After 1 month of work, where I have defined Outcomme, I would also like to
   upload all the work to SVN Repository One

The soulution I am expecting is:

1. Somethimg like a batch (any other scripting) file on which when I click at end of evry day, before leaving office, it uploads all the data to SVN Repository 2
2. Onother batch file, which if clicked will push all the data to Repository 1
3. Any other possible solution!

(We are using TortoiseSVN 1.7.12)

I am new to SVN and have absolutly no clue how to solve this, In case I have not put enough details or have not framed question correctly please let me know and I will update it.

Thanks in advance for your time and help!
Haresh

Comment: You framed everything, then what you need ?  Are you looking for SVN commands to do those 3 steps ?

Comment: Does both the repo contains same project ? If both are same use branches and merge the changes from one to another whenever you need.  It is simple to use terminal for svn than writing batch files.

Comment: @VivekShivam Thats Quick Answer! Both the repositories have same folder structure. I am not sure about how to use branches and merge. Secondly the reason for batch file is to make it less dependent on user who may not do upload every day otherwise (6 team member working on the project)

Comment: Start with this  http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/